# Symplectic geometry

Tags: reference-request, symplectic-geometry

I'm very interested in studying symplectic geometry which is compulsory in hamiltonian mechanics but sadly I just can't find a appropriate book to do that.Would anyone be helpful enough to indicate a clue?

Comment: A more advanced reference is the book by Michèle Audin, "Torus actions on symplectic manifolds".

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in Symplectic Geometry aiming at  Hamiltonian Mechanics you can take a look to

1) Hofer and Zehnder's "Symplectic Invariants  and Hamiltonian Dynamics" (Birkhäuser)

2) Abraham and Marsden's "Foundations of Mechanics"  (Addison-Wesley Publishing Company) is a formidable book about Classical Mechanics but introduces rigorously all the needed Geometry (Differentiable Manifolds, Symplectic Manifolds, Lie Groups etc).

Comment: Tributes to your knowledge!

Comment: Thanks, do not forget to accept the answer you repute more useful.

Answer (score 2):

The following are two good introductions to the subject.

Ana Cannas da Silva:*[Lectures on symplectic geometry](http://www.springer.com/in/book/9783540421955)*, Springer Lecture Notes in Mathematics **1764**.

Rolf Berndt: *[An introduction to symplectic geometry](http://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-26)*, AMS Graduate Studies in mathematics **26**.

Comment: Hi, how can I thank you!? Best regard.